# Web service to TCP Server

Tags: c#, web-services, tcp

[image]

I need to get the data from the web service to the TCP server ... what is the concept for that ?

im using C#.net

Comment: A webserver (hosting a webservice) is essentially a tcp server as well (HTTP sits on top of tcp stack). I think you are going to have to be more specific about your tcp server and provide more details around it to get useful answers.

Comment: @Sudantha, what data are you transferring?  Is this for database lookups, RSS feeds, chat services, statistics collection, RPC?  Detailed requirements help.

Comment: its a string or a image which user provide to the web service .. i needed to send to the TCP server from that web service... (Listening)

Comment: @Sudantha, why not use an existing file / string transfer protocol instead of creating your own?  FTP or SFTP can be used to transfer files efficiently.  XML / SOAP could be used to transfer a string.

Comment: thanks .. my problem is this ... when the web service get the request how to send it using FTP ? [as it got the request ]

Comment: @Sudantha, suppose they `POST` the file to your server.  As part of your `POST` response code, make a subroutine call to xfer the file via FTP.

Comment: Thanks mike im getting it ! ... i try and cme back ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, let's assume they POST the file to your server. As part of your POST response code, make a subroutine call to xfer the file via FTP.  I would avoid creating another TCP file transfer service when there are some well-implemented options (like FTP or SFTP) available.